# XNA Scale in one direction

Tags: c#, xna

I was wondering is it possible to scale a model only in one direction like x,y or z? I am aware of method `Matrix.Scale(float);` but that just scales the whole model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some overloads. Just use one of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix.createscale%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) methods. E.g.

```
Matrix.CreateScale(1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f); // Invert only one koordinate
```

Comment: Oh, didnt see that there :p Thanks.